# How to use swift in xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, frameworks

I am trying to make use of an swift based iOS Framework in xamarin.iOS

But after some research, I found that xamarin doesn't support swift language using Embedding Mono too.

How can I make use of Framework in Xamarin.iOS ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Binding *Objective C based static library is officially supported* in Xamarin.

But there is *no official support for Swift based framework* in Xamarin.iOS

1. You can import Swift based framework in Objective C based project and
   you can expose the APIs using Objective C and you can convert that into *.a static library* then you can turn that static library into a *binding library* in xamarin studio and make use of that in xamarin
2. Try porting the Swift to C# and it should be faster as well

Comment: how to port swift to c#?

Comment: The languages are similar , one should be able to do manually and that's what I did but if there are any porting tools , you could try